# .html() , innerHTML(), and .text() not changing the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried all three of these but it doesnt seem to change the text, I have a set of random quotes I want to display on the screen and I am trying to change them but the jquery methods I used dont seem to be working, here is my html and javascript code.
here's a snippet with my current code and what a I actually tried so far:

```js
    var main = function() {
  
  

    var colors = ["#ED2007", "#EDAB07", "#ECF30A", "#69F30A", "#0AF3E8", "#0A69F3", "#DE0AF3", "#F30ADE"];
      
      var quotes = [
        "If you have nothing, are you a nillionaire?",
        "Turning up the volume is like zooming in, but with sound.",
        "If I eat myself, will I get twice as big, or disappear completely?",
        "Out of my mind. Back in five minutes",
        "I’m not a complete idiot — Some parts are missing."
      ];
      
      
      //begin
      //when btn-1 is click, perform following
      $(".btn-1").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
      $this.button('loading');
        setTimeout(function() {
          //begin loop
      
      for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++){
        var randQuote = 
            ((Math.random() * quotes[i].length-1) + 0);
        
        
        switch(randQuote){
          case 0:
            
            $('#quote').html("If you have nothing, are you a nillionaire?");
            
            break;
            
          case 1:
            
            $('#quote').html("Turning up the volume is like zooming in, but with sound.");
                                             
            break;
            
          case 2:
           
            $('#quote').html("If I eat myself, will I get twice as big, or disappear completely?");
            
            break;
            
          case 3:
            
            $('#quote').html("Out of my mind. Back in five minutes");
            
            break;
            
          case 4:
           
            $('#quote').html("I’m not a complete idiot — Some parts are missing.");
            
            break;
            
          default:
            
            $('#quote').html("Press New Quote Button for a random quote");
            
        }
      }
      //end loop
      
      for(var j = 0; j < colors.length; j++){
         var randColor = Math.floor((Math.random() * colors[j].length-1) + 0);
        
        switch(randColor){
          case 0:                                       document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ED2007";
            $this.css('background-color', '#ED2007');
           break;
            
          case 1:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#EDAB07";
  

    $this.css('background-color', '#EDAB07');
                break;
            
          case 2:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor ="#ECF30A";
         $this.css('background-color', '#ECF30A');
            break;
            
          case 3:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#69F30A";
         $this.css('background-color', '#69F30A');

            break;
            
          case 4:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor ="#0AF3E8";
          $this.css('background-color', '#0AF3E8');
            break;
            
          case 5:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0A69F3";
            $this.css('background-color', '#0A69F3');
            break;
            
          case 6: 
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#DE0AF3";
            $this.css('background-color', '#DE0AF3');
            break;
            
          case 7:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="#F30ADE";
            $this.css('background-color', '#F30ADE');
            break;
            
          default:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="#00ccff";
            $this.css('background-color', '#00ccff');
 
        }
    }
       $this.button('reset');
  

     }, 4000);
    });
      //end
      
      //when tumblr btn is click, perform following
      $(".fa-tumblr-square").click(function(){
        location.href = "https://www.tumblr.com/";
      });
      
      //when twitter btn is click, perform following
      $(".fa-twitter-square").click(function(){
        location.href = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=';
      });
      
    };
    
    $(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
      <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavivanar|Supermercado+One" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <div class="head">
          <h2>Random Quote Machine</h2>
        </div>
      </head>
      
      <body>
        <p></p>
        <div class="boxed">
          <p id="quote" >"Press New Quote Button for a random quote"</p>
          <div class="btns">
     
            <i class="fa fa-tumblr-square" style="font-size:36px;color:#0A4289"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" style="font-size:36px;color:#07F5E7"></i>
            
            <button type="button" class="btn-1" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Fetching">New Quote</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <div class="footer">
          <p> <a class="link" href="https://codepen.io/natekicksa/">By:Nate</a></p>
        </div>        
      </body>
      </div>
```

Comment: are youre sure that `(Math.random() * quotes[i].length-1) + 0` return a value beetween [0-4] ? and why `+0` ? Also your var `randQuote` is decimal. I think you must use something like `Math.trunc(randQuote)` for having a number with none decimal part.

Comment: Where are you including jQuery and what errors do you get in the console?

Comment: randQuote is getting NaN from `var randQuote = 
        ((Math.random() * quotes[i].length-1) + 0);` which causes the switch to go to your default case

Comment: I posted an answer, please, look if my answer helps you @nathanHeath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the console was throwing an error in the $this.button, saying it was not a function, I changed it. 
Also, your function to get the ramdom was wrong.
Please, see if this helps you

```js
var main = function() {
  
  

    var colors = ["#ED2007", "#EDAB07", "#ECF30A", "#69F30A", "#0AF3E8", "#0A69F3", "#DE0AF3", "#F30ADE"];
      
      var quotes = [
        "If you have nothing, are you a nillionaire?",
        "Turning up the volume is like zooming in, but with sound.",
        "If I eat myself, will I get twice as big, or disappear completely?",
        "Out of my mind. Back in five minutes",
        "I’m not a complete idiot — Some parts are missing."
      ];
      
      
      //begin
      //when btn-1 is click, perform following
      $(".btn-1").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        debugger;
      $this[0].innerText  ='loading';
        setTimeout(function() {
          //begin loop
      
      for(var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++){
        var randQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length - 1) + 1);       
            $('#quote')[0].innerText = quotes[randQuote];            
        }

      
      for(var j = 0; j < colors.length; j++){
         var randColor = Math.floor((Math.random() * colors[j].length-1));
        
        switch(randColor){
          case 0:                                       document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#ED2007";
            $this.css('background-color', '#ED2007');
           break;
            
          case 1:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#EDAB07";
  

    $this.css('background-color', '#EDAB07');
                break;
            
          case 2:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor ="#ECF30A";
         $this.css('background-color', '#ECF30A');
            break;
            
          case 3:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#69F30A";
         $this.css('background-color', '#69F30A');

            break;
            
          case 4:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor ="#0AF3E8";
          $this.css('background-color', '#0AF3E8');
            break;
            
          case 5:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0A69F3";
            $this.css('background-color', '#0A69F3');
            break;
            
          case 6: 
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#DE0AF3";
            $this.css('background-color', '#DE0AF3');
            break;
            
          case 7:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="#F30ADE";
            $this.css('background-color', '#F30ADE');
            break;
            
          default:
            document.body.style.backgroundColor="#00ccff";
            $this.css('background-color', '#00ccff');
 
        }
    }
       $this[0].innerText = 'reset';
  

     }, 2000);
    });
      //end
      
      //when tumblr btn is click, perform following
      $(".fa-tumblr-square").click(function(){
        location.href = "https://www.tumblr.com/";
      });
      
      //when twitter btn is click, perform following
      $(".fa-twitter-square").click(function(){
        location.href = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=';
      });
      
    };
    
    $(document).ready(main);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
      <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavivanar|Supermercado+One" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <div class="head">
          <h2>Random Quote Machine</h2>
        </div>
      </head>
      
      <body>
        <p></p>
        <div class="boxed">
          <p id="quote" >"Press New Quote Button for a random quote"</p>
          <div class="btns">
     
            <i class="fa fa-tumblr-square" style="font-size:36px;color:#0A4289"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" style="font-size:36px;color:#07F5E7"></i>
            
            <button type="button" class="btn-1" id="load" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Fetching">New Quote</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <div class="footer">
          <p> <a class="link" href="https://codepen.io/natekicksa/">By:Nate</a></p>
        </div>        
      </body>
      </div>
```

Comment: When pressing the button I still don't see `Press New Quote Button for a random quote` being changed

Comment: Awesome! Makes a lot more sense now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: i just upvoted it but since I have less than 15 reputation it wont be displayed publicly however I checked it off as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
var min = Math.ceil(0);
var max = Math.floor(4);
randQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
```

There is no issue with .html().

The essential problem in the code is the random function. I think the code is self explanatory. Follow the link for more info on the random function:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

I also found few simple bugs by using your code:

- Instead of this.button use this.text to change the text of the button
- Include Jquery

Answer (score 0):

My guess here is that you didn't include jQuery in the head of the document. try adding this for your head and see if your jQuery functions work now:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kavivanar|Supermercado+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <div class="head">
      <h2>Random Quote Machine</h2>
    </div>
  </head>
```

This is just a guess based on the code snippet you provided above. Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @nathanHeath Is that the right answer? Somehow I got a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

`randQuote` is a float from

```
var randQuote = ((Math.random() * quotes[i].length-1) + 0);
```

such as `35.4177225431459` which causes the switch to go to your default case. You should also be using an integer to access your quotes array.

try [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) with it: `var randQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);`

Your switch case is also a little unnecessary as with the above you can now just do

```
$('#quote').text(quotes[randQuote]);
```

Comment: Awesome , makes a lot more sense now! Thanks a lot!